# Weblogic 10.3.5 - Thread dump

Tags: weblogic-10.x

I'm working with weblogic 10.3.5 under windows 7.

With one of my applications, I've got a problem when shutting donw the server :

```
<06-mai-2013 9 h 48 min 37 s CEST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000378> <Server failed to shutdown within the configured timeout of 30 seconds. The server process will exit now.>
<06-mai-2013 9 h 48 min 37 s CEST> <Error> <> <BEA-000000> <THREAD DUMP from JVM taken at 'Mon May 06 09:48:37 2013'
```

And I don't know how to go further to find the solution ...

Where is the thread dump ?

Comment: The dump log should exist under a folder like: <domain home>/servers/<server name>/logs

Comment: I don't think so.  There are logs in that folder but nothing more than what I put above.

Comment: In your top level domain folder (or the folder where you run the start script) do you see a file named something like: hs_err_pid1234.log?

Comment: No, neither log file.